# Recursive word searching to find various versions of a word

Tags: java, string

I wish to iterate through a word and print out all the different variations of it. I have wrote the code but for some reason i keep on getting an `StringIndexOutOfBoundsException`.

```
public class Test {
public static void main(String[] args) {

    String word = "telecommunications"; // loop thru this word

    for (int i = 0; i < word.length(); i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < word.length(); j++) {
            System.out.println(word.substring(i, j + 1)); 
                        //This will print out all the different variations of the word 

        }
    }
}

}
```

Can someone please tell me why I am getting this error?

Comment: Can you please tell us what is `different variations`?

Answer (score 1):

Remember, arrays are *zero-based* in Java (and most languages). 
This means, that if you have a String of length `N`, the indexes will be from `0` to `N - 1` - Which will have a total sum of `N`.

Look at this line:

```
System.out.println(word.substring(i, j + 1));
```

The length of your string is 18, the indexes are from 0 to 17.

`j` and `i` runs on this indexes, but what will happen when you do `j + 1` in the last iteration? 
- You'll get `17 + 1`, which is 18, which is *out of bounds*.

```
 j  | char at j
----+-------------
 0  |     t
 1  |     e
... |    ...
... |    ...
17  |     s
18  |    :(
```

I won't tell you the solution, but it's straight forward when you know why this is happening.

Answer (score 0):

I think you want to do something like this

```
for (int i = 0; i < word.length(); i++) {
    for (int j = i; j <= word.length(); j++) { // Change here
        System.out.println(word.substring(i, j));  // Change here
                    //This will print out all the different variations of the word
    }
}
```

You get the exception because when you try to access `j+1` with the last index, the index goes out of bounds as the max possible accessible index in any array or arraylist or string is always `n-1` where `n` is the length.

Answer (score 0):

The reason for exception is `word.substring(i, j + 1)`. 
Suppose, you are iterating through and having `i=1` & `j=17`, in that case you are trying to extract the sub-string starting from position 1 and till `i+j+1 = 19th` position, whereas you string holds only 18 characters or positions.

Answer (score 0):

Because word.substring(i, j + 1)
Here j value should be greater than i value. because first two iterations it will work fine.when third iteration i=2 j=0 at that time word.substring(2, 0 + 1) at this condition String index out of range: -1 will come  because we cannot go back word substring. second argument should be greater than first argument